# How to determine which Qt downloads to use

Tags: windows, visual-studio, qt

On the Qt download page http://qt-project.org/downloads#qt-creator, we hahve

```
Qt Online Installer for Linux 32-bit (22 MB) (Info)
Qt Online Installer for Linux 64-bit (22 MB) (Info)
Qt Online Installer for Mac (9 MB) (Info)
Qt Online Installer for Windows (13 MB) (Info)
Qt 5.1.1 for Android (Linux 32-bit, 461 MB) (Info)
Qt 5.1.1 for Android (Linux 64-bit, 459 MB) (Info)
Qt 5.1.1 for Android (Windows 32-bit, 716 MB) (Info)
Qt 5.1.1 for Linux 32-bit (417 MB) (Info)
Qt 5.1.1 for Linux 64-bit (415 MB) (Info)
Qt 5.1.1 for Mac (425 MB) (Info)
Qt 5.1.1 for Windows 32-bit (MinGW 4.8, OpenGL, 666 MB) (Info)
Qt 5.1.1 for Windows 32-bit (VS 2010, 505 MB) (Info)
Qt 5.1.1 for Windows 32-bit (VS 2010, OpenGL, 504 MB) (Info)
Qt 5.1.1 for Windows 32-bit (VS 2012, 511 MB) (Info)
Qt 5.1.1 for Windows 64-bit (VS 2012, 525 MB) (Info)
Qt 5.1.1 for Windows 64-bit (VS 2012, OpenGL, 522 MB) (Info)

Qt libraries 4.8.5 for Windows (minGW 4.4, 317 MB) (Info)
Qt libraries 4.8.5 for Windows (VS 2008, 235 MB) (Info)
Qt libraries 4.8.5 for Windows (VS 2010, 235 MB) (Info)
Qt libraries 4.8.5 for Linux/X11 (230 MB) (Info)
Qt libraries 4.8.5 for Mac (185 MB) (Info) and debug libraries (480 MB) (Info)
Qt libraries 4.8.5 for embedded Linux (230 MB) (Info)
Qt libraries 4.8.5 for Windows CE (269 MB) (Info)
```

I am really confused which one is good for me.
My situation:

Windows 7 x64, Visual Studio 2012. The project (goldendict) that I would like to work with uses VS2012 solution file. I want to build both Win32 and x64 version. The official build for Windows use Qt 4.8.5, so I am not sure if Qt 5 will cause problem. The official page says gcc is required (but I am not sure gcc is required only for build on Linux, or we need this on Windows also.)

From the above list, Qt 4.8.5 only has

```
Qt libraries 4.8.5 for Windows (minGW 4.4, 317 MB) (Info)
Qt libraries 4.8.5 for Windows (VS 2008, 235 MB) (Info)
Qt libraries 4.8.5 for Windows (VS 2010, 235 MB) (Info)
Qt libraries 4.8.5 for Windows CE (269 MB) (Info)
```

for Windows. The last one is not what I want, I am sure. But the version with "minGW", "VS2008", "VS2010"?? There is no version "VS2012". Also there is no 32-bit, 64-bit versions for Qt 4.8.5, unlike Qt 5.1.1.

I need some guide to determine which version to use, at least the most likely one.

Comment: If the project wasn't ported to Qt5, Qt5 won't work. Porting to Qt 5 is usually not a big deal, but supporting both Qt4 and Qt5 in one project is still a bit of overhead. If you're stuck with the Qt4+MSVC2012 combination, I'd suggest to compile Qt from sources, for MSVC2012.

Comment: You want this version (which is not any of the choices that you gave): http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/qt/4.8/4.8.5/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.5.zip

Answer (score 0):

Use the online installer. It lets you choose the components you want (for example, Qt for VS2012 64 bit and 32 bit). The online installer essentially lets you combine the modules you listed above.